# Django, how to display comments and replies made on that comment in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a comment table which is having a foreign key to `Blog` table. This table is used to make comments to blog and replies can be made to a comment. For this purpose i have used column `parent` which will decide to which comment the reply is made.

Now problem is that with object of this table,

```
comment_obj = comment.objects.filter(blog=blog_obj).order_by("created")
```

i am not getting the desired output. I want to know as how to display comments and under each comment the replies made to that comment.

Models.py:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User_info)
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='A')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

template:

```
{% for comment in comment_obj %}
    <li>
        {{ comment.comment }} - {{ comment.created }}
        {% for reply in comment.Comment_set.all %}
        <ul>
            {{ reply.comment }} - {{ reply.created }}
        </ul>
       {% endfor %}
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
```

But this is not working. Please help. I would like to do this without using any app.

Comment: what is not working? Does `comment.Talk_comment_set.all` return anything?

Comment: well this does not return anything, i don't think this line of code is correct

Comment: can you show the model where replies to comment are stored ?

Comment: actually this(Comment) is the only table in which both comments and replies to the comments are stored, that's why parent column

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) using an optional param to the [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) to make things simpler:

```
class comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User_info)
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, related_name='comments')
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, related_name='replies')
```

Template: (Assume `blog_obj` is the `Blog` object)

```
{% for comment in blog_obj.comments.all %}
    {{ comment.comment }}
    {% for reply in comment.replies.all %}
        {{ reply.comment }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: O man, thanks a lot. Adding related_name to the foreign key worked